# Trying to get live percentage via json from php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to update on screen without refresh the current percentage that is updated into a database when the user checks something but failed to accomplish this.
Problem is that in the console I get the error `TypeError: a is undefined ..."resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b`
and the GET request is repeated infinite. Within the get request, the response is: 
`{"percentage":null}`. An additional problem is that the GET request seams to load complete (like getting the final response) only when the php script finishes.
I checked the database and every time I refresh the database dynamically I can see the percentage updating. So it's not a problem from the PHP or SQL, may be a problem from getter.php (file that is printing the result) and the json script.
Please help me on this issue I checked the entire day + yesterday on how to echo value from database live and tried lots of examples but did not understood complete how to do it (this is mostly related to jquery knob, want to implement it there after success). Your help is much appreciated.

Jquery:

```
jQuery_1_11_0('#check').on('submit', function (e) {
    done();

    function done() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            updates();
            done();
        }, 1000);
    }

    function updates() {
        $.getJSON("lib/getter.php", function (data) {
            $("#progressbar").empty();
            $.each(data.result, function () {
                percentage = this['percentage'];
                if (percentage = null) {
                    percentage = 100;
                    $("#progressbar").html(percentage);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

process.php

```
$urlsarray = array('google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'bing.com'); 
// this is a dynamic array created by the user, I am giving just a simple example
$counter = 0;
$total = count($urls1);
$session_id = rand(100000000000000, 999999999999999);
$db->query("INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, percentage) VALUES ('$session_id', '$counter')");
foreach ($urlsarray as $urls) {
    doing some things
    $counter++;
    $percentage = ($counter/$total) * 100;
    $db->query("UPDATE sessions SET percentage = '$percentage' WHERE session_id = '$session_id'");       
}
$db->query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '$session_id'");
$percentage = 100;
```

getter.php

```
include("process.php");
global $session_id;
$readpercentage = $db->query("SELECT percentage FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '$session_id'");
$percentage = $readpercentage->fetch_assoc();
echo json_encode(array('percentage' => $percentage));
ob_flush();
flush();
```

EDIT 2 UPDATE

```
function updates() {
    $.getJSON("lib/getter.html", function (data) {
        $("#progressbar").empty();
           $("#progressbar").html(data.percentage);
    });
}
```

EDIT 3

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ updates(); }, 1000);
    function updates() {
        $.getJSON("lib/getter.html", function (data) {
            //$("#progressbar").empty();
            console.log(data);
            $("#progressbar").html(data.percentage);
            if(data.percentage >= 100){
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        });
    }
```

**EDIT 4. changed getter.php**

```
include("process.php");
//global $session_id;
//echo $session_id;
$readpercentage = $db->query("SELECT percentage FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '$session_id'");
$percentage = $readpercentage->fetch_assoc();
$percentage = (int) $percentage['percentage'];
if ($percentage = 100) {
    $percentage = 100;
}
echo json_encode(array('percentage' => $percentage));
ob_flush();
flush();
```

and the js script

```
var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);
jQuery_1_11_0('#check').on('submit', function (e) {

var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ updates(); }, 1000);
    function updates() {
        $.getJSON("lib/getter.html", function (data) {
            var percentage = data.percentage;
            $("#progressbar").html(percentage).show();
            if(percentage >= 100 || typeof percentage !== 'undefined'){
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        });
    }
});
// second script is for posting the result
jQuery_1_11_0('#check').on('submit', function (e) {
    var validatef = $("#url").val();
    var validaterror = $('#errorvalidate');
    if (validatef == 'Enter Domains Separated By New Line -MAX 100 DOMAINS-') {
        validaterror.text('Please enter domain names in the text area');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        validaterror.text('');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'lib/process.php',
            data: $('#check').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").html(data); // apple
                // $("#progressbar").knob().hide();
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();

    } // ending the else
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant help but wonder:

```
done();

function done() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        updates();
        done();
    }, 1000);
}
```

How does this recursion stops? Because to me it seems like this timeout will keep on firing eternally. You really need a timeInterval here, set it to a variable, and clear the interval when 100% has been reached.

Maybe replace the above with:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
    updates();
}, 1000);
```

then, on the updates function

```
if(percentage >= 100){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

By the way, doing:

```
if(percentage = null){
    ...
}
```

Did you mean to compare using = instead of == ? If you want to verify that percentage is set and is a valid number, it would probably be a good idea to do:

```
if(typeof percentage !== 'undefined' && !isNaN(parseFloat(percentage)){
    ...
}
```

Comment: true, this is what I am trying to figure out, how to add setinterval to my function

Comment: Just replace your done(); call and the done() function itself by the block I posed right after with the time interval, it should do the same thing. And then just stop the interval by calling clearInterval(myInterval); when you want it to stop updating.

Comment: Updated EDIT 3 , this is how the function looks now. tried also only with data variable, but now I can see what console.log is returning and is returning null. for both: console.log(data); and console.log(data.percentage); and this is why is running infinite.

Comment: Ok, if your data variable is null means that you are getting nothing back from the ajax call. You first had 

    $.getJSON("lib/getter.php", function (data) {

was your call when posted your question, but somehow you changed it to

    $.getJSON("lib/getter.html", function (data) {

Try changing it back to a .php extension (which is probably what you meant, since you didnt post anything regarding a .html file.

Comment: Yep, added `if(data.percentage >= 100 || typeof data.percentage !== 'undefined'){` and infinite loop is gone, because indeed is recing null, but don't get it why, in getter php everything seems to be ok

Comment: Ok, managed to get the correct value, changed accordingly to EDIT 4 (added also the post script that returns the result). Problem now is that the GET and POST request are not working on multi tasking. Like the GET request won't get the result live until the script with the foreach finishes.

Answer (score 2):

Look at what you're sending back to your JS code from PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array('percentage' => $percentage));
```

Literally that'll be

```
{"percentage":42}
```

In your JS code, you then have:

```
    $.getJSON("lib/getter.php", function (data) {
                                          ^^^^---the data coming back from PHP
        ....
        $.each(data.result, function () {
                    ^^^^^^---since when did you put a "result" key into your array?
```

For this JS code to work, you'd have to be doing

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => $percentage));
                        ^^^^^^---note the new key.
```

And note that since you're sending back a SINGLE object in the JSON, with a single key:value pair, there is literally no point in using your inner `$.each()` loop. You could just as well have

```
$("#progressbar").html(data.percentage);
```

Comment: Edited as you said (instead of editing php, edited json check EDIT 2), and now I don't get anymore error, but I still don't receive the value from php and the get requests work infinite. Your help it's much appreciated. You have an impressing rep.

Comment: do a `console.log(data)` in the JS code to see exactly what's coming back from the server. then start figuring out where the problem is. As well, your setTimeout should probably just be a setInterval, which is intended for repeated calls. As it stands now, you have no way of STOPPING your update calls when things really are done. You'll just keep hammering the server once a second until the browser quits/crashes/goes elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, console.log not helping because they are running infinite not stopping to get the response. Based on my code how do I do a setinterval, trying to figure out, but I am blurred (I am no expert in jquery)

Comment: settimeout/setinterval are JS-native functions. no jquery necessary.

Comment: Almost done, if you have time please check EDIT 4 and last comment from Victor's response.